# Ruby on Rails - Testing the contents of a CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

So I have a link on my rails web page that generates a CSV file. How would I go about writing a functional test to test that the CSV file is created properly and check the contents of it?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways. Here's a version that won't make you jump through browser hoops

1. Extract the creation of a CSV to another non-controller class
2. In your controller test, assert your CreatesCSV receives the right parameters
3. Test your CreatesCSV class by writing its output to a file, then reading it in and verifying the hash is correct.